# POSTGRES : Error while returning JSON result from QUERY

Tags: postgresql

I have created one function which is doing following steps :

1. Preparing dynamic query
   2)Execute query
2. returns result of query as JSON

Cannot share actual code but sharing custom code

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
  RETURNS TABLE(j json) AS
$$
DECLARE
    stmt1 varchar(32767) := NULL;
    
    tbl_name varchar(40) := 'xtest';
  
begin
     
           
         stmt1 :=   'select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(data1)) from  (select  a.fst_name,  a.LAST_NAME ';
        stmt1 := CONCAT_WS('', stmt1, ' from ', tbl_name, ' a limit 2 )data1');
       
  RETURN QUERY execute stmt1;
  

   
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


select test()
```

Error I am getting

```
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type¶  Detail: Returned type jsonb does not match expected type json in column 1.¶  Where: SQL statement "select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(data1)) from  (select  a.fst_name,  a.LAST_NAME  from test a limit 2 )data1"¶PL/pgSQL function test() line 21 at RETURN QUERYSQL Error [42804]: ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type¶  Detail: Returned type jsonb does not match expected type json in column 1.¶  Where: SQL statement "select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(data1)) from  (select  a.fst_name,  a.LAST_NAME  from xtest a limit 2 )data1"¶PL/pgSQL function test() line 21 at RETURN QUERY
```

Comment: `Cannot share complete code` and we cannot guess what is wrong is this classified piece of code.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have shared the result of dynamic  query which I am running using  return query execute part. Ia m show why query result is considered as multiple rows. But I will still share some custom code to check issue

Comment: What happens if you change your `returns table(j json)` to `returns json`?

Comment: When I convert it to json ERROR: cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function

Comment: The documentation is there for a reason read it [Returning from function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) and [Dynamic  SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) and learn.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have updated simple custom code . I am doing something similar in my actual code

Comment: 1) Again read the links  I posted earlier, especially the `Dynamic SQL` one. That would eliminate this `stmt1 := CONCAT_WS(' ...` monstrosity.  2) Read the error message, it is telling you what the problem is. Hint `jsonb_agg` and `to_jsonb` are the wrong functions.

Comment: Thank you so much I changed jsonb_agg to row_to_jsson and it worked .